# Doing an INSERT INTO tableA with sub-SELECT on tableB sorted with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a table, tableA that I want to resort and then insert / update each resulting row into tableB.  Currently I have something like this:

```
delete from tableB;
set @place = 0;
INSERT INTO tableB (id, place, name, colD, colF) SELECT (id, greatest(@place := @place + 1, 0) from tableA order by colD desc;
```

This works, but I don't want to delete from tableB each time as the table will likely contain hundred of thousands of rows.  So, I wanted to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as each id column is set as a PRIMARY KEY.  I have tried various versions of the following (moving the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause around)

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, place, name, colD, colF) SELECT (id, greatest(@place := @place + 1, 0) from tableA order by colD desc ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tableB.place = @place, tableB.name = tableA.name, tableB.colD = tableA.colD, tableB.colF = tableA.colF;
```

NO LUCK,

Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by resort? RDBs are not sorted, you can sort in your select query, and support this by using an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use views for this purpose?

```
create view tableb as 
SELECT (id, greatest(@place := @place + 1, 0) from tableA order by colD desc;
```

That way will have less problems because it will be automatically updated.

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html)